# How to reflow long to wide only part and summarise the rest?

Tags: r, data.table

I need to arrange a table by performing some formatting, with a table like

```
DT <- read.table(text = 
"Year   ST_ID    N   Overall  Metric1  Metric2
1999    205    386     96.3        0       0    
1999    205     15        0        0       0
1999    205      0        0        0       0  
1999    205      0        0        0      NA
2000    205    440      100        0       0
2000    205      0        0        0       0
2000    205      0        0       NA       0
2000    205      0        0        0      NA", header = TRUE)
```

I need to obtain the following "Output" table.

```
Year   ST_ID    1   2  3  4  Overall  Metric1  Metric2
1999    205   386  15  0  0     96.3        0      NA    
2000    205   440   0  0  0      100       NA      NA
 .
 .
```

In the columns on the right, I want to aggregate any instances of NA => to NA else sum(values)

How can I achieve this using R?

Comment: For clarity, I would add a description of how you want to aggregate each column e.g. "any instance of NA => NA, else sum(values)".

Comment: Yes I want to aggregate any instances of NA => to NA else sum(values).

Comment: Please amend your question to reflect this. It's important piece of information. Also, next time, I suggest you share your data in an easy to paste form.

Comment: @SymbolixAU I think this is not a duplicate as it needs two stages to reflow to wide.

Answer (score 1):

With the data.table package, there's

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

DT[, c(
  setNames(as.list(N), seq_along(N)),
  lapply(.SD, sum)
), by=.(Year, ST_ID), .SDcols = Overall:Metric2]

#    Year ST_ID   1  2 3 4 Overall Metric1 Metric2
# 1: 1999   205 386 15 0 0    96.3       0      NA
# 2: 2000   205 440  0 0 0   100.0      NA      NA
```

*How it works*

See the package vignettes for an introduction. In this case, the syntax is `DT[, j, by=, .SDcols=]`.

- `j` is a list, with each element corresponding to a column in the result.
- `.SDcols=` optionally allows for defining a set of columns of `DT`.
- `by=` optionally allows for computing `j` separately per group.

Comment: actually the `sum` function does the `if else` statement that you have. you can simply have it as `lapply(.SD,sum)`

Answer (score 1):

```
 library(tidyr)   
 A=aggregate(.~Year,xy[-(2:3)],sum,na.action=function(x)x)
 xy[1:3]%>%group_by(Year)%>%mutate(N_=1:4)%>%spread(N_,N,sep="")%>%merge(A,by="Year")
  Year ST_ID N_1 N_2 N_3 N_4 Overall Metric1 Metric2
1 1999   205 386  15   0   0    96.3       0      NA
2 2000   205 440   0   0   0   100.0      NA      NA
```

Hope this helps.

I think there can be a better way to aggregate. eg the `na.action` should take an Identity function(a function that returns the input) such as the `I` function in base R. although the `I` function changes the class of the object to `AsIs` and this is a challenge to me within the `aggregate function`. `class(I(xy))`.